# “Although A and B are” vs “Despite A and B being”

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I would like to know if the following sentences have the same meaning:

> 1. Although John and Tom are the most hard-working students, they did not pass the final exam.
> 2. Despite John and Tom being the most hard-working students, they did not pass the final exam.

Comment: I believe, they are similar in meaning. The difference: although = conjunction; despite = preposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition *despite* and the conjunction *although* are both used to show a contrast, but the structures they are used in are different:

After "despite" *a noun or a pronoun* is used, whereas after "although"-- *a subject and a verb*, as is in your first sentence:

> Although John and Tom are the most hard-working students, they did not
>   pass the final exam.

To use "despite" with a subject and verb you need to include the expression ‘the fact that’. So the correct version of your second sentence may be:

> Despite the fact that John and Tom are/were the most hard-working students,
>   they did not pass the final exam.

where "despite the fact that" and "although" can be used interchangeably.

At the same time, as it is written in the example sentence, it doesn't seem incorrect to me, "John and Tom being the most hard-working students" being regarded as a noun.

[The source](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/intermediate-grammar/spite-despite-although).

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are understood to mean the same thing. Although, *although* is used in a different sense quite frequently and in that sense, you are saying, the John is still the most hard working student, whether he failed the test or not, which is quite different from *despite*.

The German analog *jedoch* couldn't be used fronted like that, so something must have gone wrong on one end. It can only couple phrases. In that sense, it could appear in the beginning of a sentence, coupling the preceding sentence, but that's a different matter.

I don't know man, *though* is used inflationary these days.

Comment: @ vectory despite sth. =  trotz einer Sache;  although = obwohl -> 1. Obwohl John und Tom die fleißigsten Schüler sind, haben sie die Abschlussprüfung nicht bestanden. 2. Trotz der Tatsache, dass John und Tom die fleißigsten Schüler sind, haben sie die Abschlussprüfung nicht bestanden.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @vectory. However, I didn't understand quite well the difference in meaning of "although" and "despite". I also did not understand why referring to a German analog.

Comment: @re_nez, is it possible for you to translate your comment to English? I don't understand German, but I'm interested in your comment.

Comment: @r-joe That's because you don't understand German, I suppose. See, your *although* there is completely, well almost, useless. Without it, the sentence has anaphora to convey the meaning. That makes its use difficult to explain. Comparing my alternative interpretation to German, where this sentence doesn't have an analog, was supposed to show that my interpretation doesn't work well, and that's feasable, because the syntax is similar, sharing roots in part. Either way, it shows where my notion is coming from. It's also very clearly a half assed answer.

Comment: @re_nez: see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/how-to-interpret-the-meaning-of-jedoch-in-terms-of-je-and-doch but what you said is not wrong. Of course.